# Error with nvarchar?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have created a database but this error really annoyed me and I have tried every trick with it but it keeps coming back. It works fine but sometimes when I add a row or delete one from one of the tables it just don't get back any rows but When I put N before dollarPrice it will be ok again but when I make changes to the tables same error occurs again then I have to remove the N it works again. It's really frustrating please any help??? the code is below...

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("WITH tbl AS (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN PayType = 2 AND CurrencyType = 1 THEN " +
"TotalPrice END), 0) AS [PurchaseTotalD]," +
"ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN PayType = 2 AND CurrencyType = 2 THEN " +
"TotalPrice / N'" & dollarPrice & "' END), 0) AS [PurchaseTotalID]," +
"(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN CurrencyType = 1 THEN Amount END), 0) FROM PayCompany) AS [PayCompanyTotalD]," +
"(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN CurrencyType = 2 THEN " +
"Amount / N'" & dollarPrice & "' END), 0) FROM PayCompany) AS [PayCompanyTotalID]," +
"(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN CurrencyType = 1 THEN Amount END), 0) FROM Expenses) AS [ExpensesTotalD]," +
"(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN CurrencyType = 2 THEN " +
"Amount / N'" & dollarPrice & "' END), 0) FROM Expenses) AS [ExpensesTotalID]," +
"(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN PayType = 2 AND CurrencyType = 1 THEN TotalDiscount END), 0) FROM Cashier) AS [CashierTotalD]," +
"(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN payType = 2 AND CurrencyType = 2 THEN " +
"TotalDiscount / N'" & dollarPrice & "' END), 0) FROM Cashier) AS [CashierTotalID]," +
"(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN CurrencyType = 1 THEN Amount END), 0) FROM PayCashier) AS [PayCashierTotalD]," +
"(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN CurrencyType = 2 THEN " +
"Amount / N'" & dollarPrice & "' END), 0) FROM PayCashier) AS [PayCashierTotalID]," +
"(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN CurrencyType = 1 THEN PaidMoney END), 0) FROM Installments) AS [InstallmentsTotalD]," +
"(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN CurrencyType = 2 THEN " +
"PaidMoney / N'" & dollarPrice & "' END), 0) FROM Installments) AS [InstallmentsTotalID] FROM Purchase)" +
"(SELECT (CashierTotalD + CashierTotalID + PayCashierTotalD + PayCashierTotalID + InstallmentsTotalD + InstallmentsTotalID) - " +
"(PurchaseTotalD + PurchaseTotalID +  PayCompanyTotalD + PayCompanyTotalID + ExpensesTotalD + ExpensesTotalID) AS [Purse] FROM tbl)", con)

    Dim da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd11)
    Dim dt = New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    PurseTB.Text = "$" & FormatNumber(dt.Rows(0).Item("Purse"), 3)
```

Comment: Oh wow this is bad. Do not build queries of this complexity in code - they belong in backend stored procedure. Otherwise it will be a pain to debug. Or, if you absolutely must - use a StringBuilder and parameters - that thing above is unreadable and a huge security risk

Comment: Thanks for your reply Haven't used StringBuilder yet. yeah the code is very complex but the database is so big I have to do this otherwise I can't do it. any other fixes????